# How can I create an Elasticsearch Query DSL for finding objects with empty array OR a value in same object

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am searching for objects in Elasticsearch 6.3.

I have 3 objects:

```
{
  identifier: 01,
  lineCodes: [],
},
{
  identifier: 02,
  lineCodes: [
    {
       link: "brussels",
       name: "br"
    },
    {
       link: "antwerp",
       name: "an"
    },
  ],
},
{
  identifier: 03,
  lineCodes: [
    {
       link: "ghent",
       name: "gh"
    },
  ],
}
```

My lineCodes schema is:

```
{
  "lineCodes": {
    "properties": {
      "__typename": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "link": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can you help me with Query DSL's that find all objects with:

1. Brussels in lineCodes.link or empty lineCodes
2. All empty lineCodes
3. Ghent in lineCodes.link or empty lineCodes

query 1 should result in object 01 and 02

query 2 should result in object 01

query 3 should result in object 01 and 03

I tried this query, but it gives me not the empty LineCodes objects

```
let query = {
    size: 1000,
    index: 'catalog',
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              bool: {
                should: [
                  { term: { 'lineCodes.link': lineCode } },
                  { terms: { 'lineCodes': [] } },
                ],
              },
            }
          ],
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `exists` query ( [doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) ) and negate it with a must_not clause in a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Could you try :

```
{
    size: 1000,
    index: 'catalog',
    body: {
      query: {
        bool: {
          must: [
            {
              bool: {
                should: [
                  { term: { 'lineCodes.link': lineCode } },
                  {
                    bool: {
                      must_not: {
                        exists: {
                          field: 'lineCodes'
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
              },
            }
          ],
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

NB: As you use a term query for linecode.link watch out for case and accents!

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly I was looking for. I tried it also with `must_not` exits`, but forgot to put a bool before. Thank you very much.